# Breakpoint and Font Size Confusion

Tags: css, media-queries, breakpoints, font-size

I am working on a Media Query element of my portfolio where the breakpoint's conversion is leading to different font sizes. For example -

if the breakpoint is 1200px then the em would be 75. so why the font-size is 60%?

```
@media (max-width: 75em) {html {font-size: 60%;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the font-size to be 75em up to 1200px, then you need this:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {html {font-size: 75em;}}
```

Your posted example means, that the breakpoint is at 75em and the font-size shown is set to 60%. Without the full code it is absolute not possible to say what sizes these numbers generate because 'em' and '%' are relative to the root-font-size.